# call a function in jquery namespace from outside the jquery namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the code

```
test ('e');
function test(e) {
    test2(e); //undefined
}

(function ($) {
    function test2(e) {
        alert('test');
    }
})
```

Because of something restriction, i have to call like this. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, by declaring `test2` outside the anonymous function:

```
var test2;                     //Declare test2 in global
(function ($) {
    test2 = function (e) {     //define test2 
        alert('test');         //because test2 was declared in global,
    };                         // it will stay global.
})(jQuery);

test('e');                     //Call test

function test(e) {
    test2(e);                  //Since test2 can be access anywhere in your code,
}                              //it is now defined.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LEZkt/

Comment: 得閒解答吓人哋D問題…如果你想上SO吹水嘅話可以嚟我哋開嘅[chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12327/chinese)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the function `test2` has been defined in the closure, you can only call the function within that scope.

Answer (score 0):

bind event on document and trigger it:

```
function test(e) {
        var param=1;
            param2=4;
        jQuery(document).trigger('mytest2',[param,param2]); 
    }
(function ($) {
    $(document).bind('mytest2',test2);    
    function test2(event,param,param2) {
        alert('test '+param+' '+param2);
    }
})(jQuery)
setTimeout(test,2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CzNKu/